# Clean up If or syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fhBd5/

So the above is working but I'm having trouble trying to come up with a clean and concise way to do some type of loop on the if or statements.

Any help is very much appreciated!

```
var checkPositionOnLoad = function (e) {
        var currentPos = 0;
        var listItem = document.getElement('li.current');
        var currentSelected = $('list').getChildren('li').indexOf(listItem) + 1;

        if (currentSelected <= 3) {
            return false;
        }
        if(currentSelected==4||currentSelected==5||currentSelected==6){
            currentPos = -300 * 1;
            $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);      
        }
        else if(currentSelected== 7||currentSelected==8||currentSelected==9){
            currentPos = -300 * 2;
            $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);      
        }
        else if(currentSelected==10||currentSelected==11||currentSelected==12){
            currentPos = -300 * 3;
            $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);      
        }
        else if(currentSelected==13||currentSelected==14||currentSelected==15){
            currentPos = -300 * 4;
            $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);       
        };

    };
```

Comment: Please post code into question. We can grantee that http://jsfiddle.net will be available in the future and thus the question may becomes meaningless for other people when reading it.

Comment: @LokiAstari not a problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my slightly "mathematical" version of the function you have posted:

```
var checkPositionOnLoad = function (e) {
    var currentPos = 0;
    var listItem = document.getElement('li.current');
    var currentSelected = $('list').getChildren('li').indexOf(listItem) + 1;

    currentPos = -300 * (Math.floor((currentSelected + 2) / 3) - 1);

    $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);
};
```

I will try to explain how I got to that succinct version.

I removed the duplication and wrote the function as follows:

```
var checkPositionOnLoad = function (e) {
    var currentPos = 0;
    var listItem = document.getElement('li.current');
    var currentSelected = $('list').getChildren('li').indexOf(listItem) + 1;

    if (currentSelected <= 3) {
        currentPos = -300 * 0;
    }
    if (currentSelected == 4 || currentSelected == 5 || currentSelected == 6) {
        currentPos = -300 * 1;
    }
    else if (currentSelected == 7 || currentSelected == 8 || currentSelected == 9) {
        currentPos = -300 * 2;
    }
    else if (currentSelected == 10 || currentSelected == 11 || currentSelected == 12) {
        currentPos = -300 * 3;
    }
    else if (currentSelected == 13 || currentSelected == 14 || currentSelected == 15) {
        currentPos = -300 * 4;
    };

    $('list').setStyle('left', currentPos);
};
```

Then I realized you want to figure where a given selected element falls (in which group of triplets that is {1, 2, 3} {4, 5, 6}, etc..). I played around and came up with a mathematical formula:

```
Math.floor((i + 2) / 3)
```

This basically tells you that for i = 7, the selected element falls in the third group `{7, 8, 9}` which is the third triplet after `{1, 2, 3}` and `{4, 5, 6}`

And the `left` property can be set using:

```
var currentPos = -300 * (Math.floor((i + 2) / 3) - 1); // (-1 to make it zero-based index)
```

And that's it.